# Jquery on click one sub element toggle another sub element of same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, children

I am having the below code and have multiple parent divs on same page.

```
<div class="full-width" id="edit">
   <img id="edit-click" class="responsive" src="./images/icon.png">
   <div id="editable" class="editable"> 1 </div>
</div>

<div class="full-width" id="edit">
   <img id="edit-click" class="responsive" src="./images/icon.png">
   <div id="editable" class="editable"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is : on clicking the image(#edit-click) the sub element (#editable) div should open up only for that particular parent div.

How can I achieve this.. ?

### I am trying this

```
$('#edit').on('click', '#edit-click', function (e) {
   $(this).children('#editable').fadeIn( "slow");
});
```

---

but this is not targetting the #editable div of the same parent div :(

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you can make that using classes but don't use same id for more than one element .. you can take a look at my answer

Comment: I know this is a little bit confused about id must be unique while it can works fine with css .. but you can try click event here  it will just work with the first element https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1vrdbzgL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id must be unique insetad take class as selector

Like this

```
$(".full-width").on("click", ".responsive", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".editable").fadeIn("slow");
})
```

Comment: it was not working with .closest. but working fine with .siblings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> As I said Id must be unique *(I know this is a little bit confused
>   about id must be unique while it can works fine with css .. but you
>   can try click event here  it will just work with the first element
>   https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1vrdbzgL/  and you can take a
>   look at
>   [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)*

so your code should be something like this

in html

```
<div class="full-width" id="edit1">
   <img id="edit-click1" class="responsive" src="./images/icon.png">
   <div id="editable1" class="editable"> 1 </div>
</div>

<div class="full-width" id="edit2">
   <img id="edit-click2" class="responsive" src="./images/icon.png">
   <div id="editable2" class="editable"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

in js you need to use `.closest()` and `.find()`

```
$('.full-width').on('click', '.responsive', function (e) {
   $(this).closest('.full-width').find('.editable').fadeIn( "slow");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1vrdbzgL/3/)

**Additional**  for fadeToggle you can use

```
$('.full-width').on('click', '.responsive', function (e) {
   var getEditable = $(this).closest('.full-width').find('.editable');
   $('.editable').not(getEditable).hide();
   getEditable.fadeToggle( "slow");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1vrdbzgL/2/)

> **Note:** be sure you include jquery

Comment: Hey Yousef thanks for adding the unique id part to my knowledge. Appreciate it very much !!

Comment: @JasdeepSingh glad to hear that .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You better do it this way.

```
<div class="full-width" id="edit1">
   <img class="edit-click responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
   <div id="editable1" class="editable"> 1 </div>
</div>

<div class="full-width" id="edit2">
  <img class="edit-click responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/51">
  <div id="editable2" class="editable"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

Use classes instead of IDs.

And use CSS classes instead of *jQuery* **fadeIn**, **fadeOut**.

```
.editable {
   display: none;
} 

.active .editable {
   display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hje00xyg/